# What are the odds of guessing 3 out of 4 numbers of a pin correctly, out of order?

Tags: probability

So the probability of guessing a four digit pin is $\frac{1}{10000}$, given that the possible combinations are $0000$-$9999$.

Guessing one digit (in order) correctly is $\frac{1}{10}$, the second $\frac{1}{10}$, the third $\frac{1}{10}$, the fourth $\frac{1}{10}$.

What are the odds of guessing $\frac{3}{4}$ numbers of a pin correctly, but out of order?

Comment: All out of order? Or at least one out of order?

Comment: All out of order.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we must require that the correct PIN have distinct digits for the question to make sense.  If so, there are $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7=5040$ PINs available. Now if we require that the three digits that match are in the same positions, there are $4$ ways to select which three digits will be correct, $3!-1=5$ incorrect orders, and $5$ choices for the incorrect digit, for a total of $100$ incorrect PINs meeting the requirement.  If we accept any order of the digits except the correct one, we have $4$ ways to choose the three digits that will be right, $5$ ways to choose the wrong digit, and $4!-1=23$ incorrect orders for the four digits, for a total of $460$.  In that case, the chance of guessing this is $\frac {460}{5040} \approx 9.1\%$, not nearly as small as one would think.

Comment: Digits can repeat though, just be out of order. So if we have 2612 as our pin, our guess might be 6128.

Comment: You need to carefully define what you mean by three out of four right and out of order.  Once you have done so, the above technique will get you there.  It will take some casework because of duplicates-if the right one is 2612, do you accept 2172?  It is hard to tell, but the 2's have switched places.

Comment: @incarna If the number is $\color{blue}1\color{red}123$ and you guess $3\color{purple}142$ do you have three correct guesses out of order? What about $3\color{purple}1\color{purple}12$ ?